# Nested depth exceeded

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, c++, dapp

```
kipping set abi because the new abi is the same as the existing abi
Publishing contract...
Error 3070002: Runtime Error Processing WASM
Error Details:
Nested depth exceeded
pending console output:
```

above error occurred while compile my contract, any hint?

Comment: What CDT are you using?  Use 1.7 (1.8 is broken)

Comment: i am using cdt 1.7

Answer (score 0):

the only thing I could find out about this issue is this
https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/4825#issuecomment-407312395